# System76 Boring Backlight, how to control it?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-backlight, coreboot, dasharo

I ever dislike the keyboards with lights, today after firmware update on my NS5x_NS7xPU the keyboard..become "with backlight".
How to turn off?
I have tried this command as root

```
sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/system76_acpi::kbd_backlight/max_brightness"
sh: line 1: /sys/class/leds/system76_acpi::kbd_backlight/max_brightness: Permission denied
```

When I press fn+f7 it appear a "monitor configuration" of Xfce4

When I run this command

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/system76_acpi\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

the keyboard backlight is still on,

Comment: `max_brightness` is the maximum brightness that you *could* set. It's not the thing you set.

Comment: Thanks cat /sys/class/leds/system76_acpi\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
report 0 but the lights are on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, waiting for controller by system i press two keyboard keys..

```
FN+*
```